# slack show webhooks configured for user when they leave

Tags: slack

We've had a DevOps member leave recently and have had complaints that all of the integrations (incoming webhooks) that they had set up have stopped working... (once the user was disabled).

One suggestion for dealing with this was to notify the affected channels when we deactivate the user, but I can't find in the API methods a way to look up which channels a user might have configured these webhooks for...

Anyone had to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the apps and internal integrations that have been installed by a specific user use the API method called [`team.integrationLogs`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.integrationLogs).

> This method lists the integration activity logs for a team, including
>   when integrations are added, modified and removed. This method can
>   only be called by Admins.

For a programmatic solution you will need to go through all log entries for one user / app to find out its latest status.

However, it might still become difficult to reinstall all that apps / setup all that webhooks again properly after a DevOps member has left depending on how good your documentation is. We have therefore started using a generic admin user (e.g. "slackadmin") as main installer for all important apps / integrations for our workspace.